# task is not mapped using JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

For three hours i have trying to fix the code below.
All the time I get the message :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: task is not mapped [from task]

In class JpaToDoList, displays a warning in line 
taskList = entityManager.createQuery("from task").getResultList();
I don't have any, how i can fix the project nad Has anyone have any idea where i can look for an error??

Task.java

```
package test.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


package test.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table( name="task")
public class Task {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstname;
@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastname;

    public Task() {}
    public Task(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstName;
        this.lastname = lastName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Task#" + id + " dla " + firstname+" "+lastname;
    }

    public Task(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="taskmanager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
          <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
          <class>test.spring.model.Task</class>          
     </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

jpa:

```
package test.spring.service;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import test.spring.model.Task;


@Service 
@Qualifier("jpa")
public class JpaToDoList implements ToDoListStrategy {
List<Task>taskList;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public List<Task> createListTasks() {
        taskList = (List<Task>) entityManager.createQuery("select e from Task e").getResultList();
        return taskList;
    }
}
```

After Yours amendments, i get a next error "No default constructor for entity:  : test.spring.model.Task"

**The above code contains fixes.**

Comment: Your entity is named `Task`, not `task`.

Comment: and JPQL requires "SELECT task" on the front of that query

Comment: ok, but i get a next error : No default constructor for entity: : test.spring.model.Task

Comment: The bit in the JPA spec that says all entities "must have a no-arg constructor and it must be public/protected".

Comment: thank you very much for yours assistance